# Integrating the Pochhammer symbol. $\int_{-1}^{1} \prod_{j=0}^{\infty} (1-x^{j+1})$

Tags: pochhammer-symbol

I had a question regarding the Pochhammer symbol, specifically integrating $[x;x]_{\infty} = \prod_{j=0}^{\infty} (1-x^{j+1})$. Firstly, is there a closed form for the $n^{th}$ partial product of this, or $[x;x]_{n+1}$? I tried computing the first 3 partial products and couldn't find a pattern.

Secondly, is there a closed form for the area under this from $0$ to $1$?  I was thinking about trying to find a closed form for $[x,x]_n$ as a series, then you can integrate the series and get a series representation of the integral, but if I don't know a closed form for $[x,x]_n$, this isn't useful. Can someone help?

This is just for personal interest, as I just learned about the Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: I believe I answered this question a few years ago on Quora:   https://qr.ae/pvYZ2s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know a closed form for
$$I_n=\int_{-1}^{+1} (x;x)_{n+1}\,dx$$

For even values of $n$, this generates the sequence
$$\left\{2,\frac{152}{105},\frac{4672}{3465},\frac{333280768}{253161909},\frac{141841
   28217088}{10883356008525},\frac{257964528813440303104}{198899418641149766925}\right\}$$ For odd values of $n$
$$\left\{\frac{4}{3},\frac{128}{99},\frac{328448}{255255},\frac{34963456}{27188525},
   \frac{530068713377923072}{412106981947605945}\right\}$$ which both decrese when $n$ increase. As you wrote, I do not see any clear pattern.
I did not find these terms in $OEIS$.

Concerning

$$I_\infty=\int_{-1}^{+1} (x;x)_\infty\,dx$$ it is just a number $\color{red}{\text{(this is WRONG})}$
$$I_\infty=1.28830088867392123018090\cdots$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

**Edit** *(after @Brian Constantinescu's comment)*

In [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-int_-1-1-prod_-n-1-infty-left-1-x-n-right-dx/answer/Brian-Constantinescu?ch=10&oid=142640196&share=bb101177&srid=3QH4K&target_type=answer), using residues, @Brian Constantinescu provided a very elegant closed form of the result.

Simplifying his last result
$$I_\infty=\int_{-1}^{+1} (x;x)_\infty\,dx=4\pi \sqrt{\frac{6}{23}}\,\, \frac{\sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23}
   \pi }{4}\right)+\sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{6}\right)}{2 \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{3}\right)-1}$$

Using the same steps and notations as @Brian Constantinescu, computing the sums in terms of polylogarithms and simplifying, we have
$$A=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3 n^2-n+2}$$ $$A=-\frac{i \pi  \left(\tan \left(\frac{1}{12} \left(5+i \sqrt{23}\right) \pi \right)+\cot
   \left(\frac{1}{12} \left(5+i \sqrt{23}\right) \pi \right)-2 \csc \left(\frac{1}{6}
   \left(1+i \sqrt{23}\right) \pi \right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{23}}$$ Expanding the complex numbers
$$\color{blue}{A=4 \pi \sqrt{\frac{3}{23}}\,\,\frac{\sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{6}\right)}{2 \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi}{3}\right)-1}} $$
$$B_x=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^x}{12 x^2-2 x+2}$$
$$B_x=\frac{i \pi  \left(\csc \left(\frac{1}{12} \left(1+i \sqrt{23}\right) \pi
   \right)-\text{sech}\left(\frac{1}{12} \left(\sqrt{23}-5 i\right) \pi \right)\right)}{2\sqrt{23}}$$
$$\color{blue}{B_x=-\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{23}} \left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)\,\,\frac{\sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{12}\right)}{\sqrt{3}-2 \cosh
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{6}\right)}}$$
$$B_y=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^y}{12 y^2+10 y+4}$$
$$B_y=\frac{i \pi  \left(\csc \left(\frac{1}{12} \left(5+i \sqrt{23}\right) \pi
   \right)-\text{sech}\left(\frac{1}{12} \left(\sqrt{23}-i\right) \pi \right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{23}}$$
$$\color{blue}{B_y=\pi\sqrt{\frac{2}{23}} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\,\,\frac{\sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{12}\right)}{\sqrt{3}+2 \cosh
   \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{6}\right)}}$$
$$\color{red}{I_\infty=2(A+B_x+B_y)=4\pi \sqrt{\frac{6}{23}}\,\, \frac{\sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23}
   \pi }{4}\right)+\sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{6}\right)}{2 \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{3}\right)-1}}$$

Comment: I believe the integral does have a closed-form due to Euler's Pentagonal Number Theorem for the case where $n\to\infty$

Comment: @BrianConstantinescu. Your solution in Quora is more than elegant and beautiful. Tell me if you plan to add the solution here as an answer. If you do not, I shall edit and, quoting you for sure, I shall add the end result. Cheers and thanks.

Comment: Certainly would be happy if you adapted the work here. My rambling post doesn't blend well with the brevity and precision found on StackExchange.

Comment: You can find a complete closed-form here: http://oeis.org/A258232/a258232_2.pdf

Comment: @BrianConstantinescu. In Quora, I think that there is a typo : the last $(\sqrt 3+1)$ is probably $(\sqrt 3-1)$

Comment: @BrianConstantinescu.  I made your result more compact.

Comment: @BrianConstantinescu. You inspired me a lot ! Look at my edit (without residues). Cheers :-)

Comment: Awesome work! I'm glad to see this nice compact solution. All the best!

Comment: Thank you all for your help with this! Claude, how did you get this expression for A? You mention the use of the polylog, which I am familiar with, but don't readily see how to get it. Thanks.

Comment: @Luna145. Have a look at  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2F%282+-+2*n+%2B+3*n%5E2%29%2C%7Bn%2C-Infinity%2CInfinity%7D%5D and simplify (a lot). Otherwise, use partial fraction decomposition and use $$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty\frac {(-1)^n}{n-\gamma}=-\pi  \csc (\pi  \gamma )$$